# sequelize/sequelize-typescript - findAll with HasMany returns an object instead of an array

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to make a one-to-many relationship using sequelize-typescript.
But when I try to get the data, the relationship for many, returns me an object instead of an array

I have two tables. Team and Players.

Team can has many players, and a player belongs to a team.

My models:

```
@Table
export class Team extends Model<Team> {
  @Column
  name: string

  @HasMany(() => Player)
  players: Player[]
}

@Table
export class Player extends Model<Player> {
  @Column
  name: string

  @Column
  num: number

  @ForeignKey(() => Team)
  @Column
  teamId: number

  @BelongsTo(() => Team)
  team: Team
}
```

When I run:

```
Team.findAll({ include: [Player] })
```

I get this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Team",
    "createdAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z",
    "players": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Player One",
      "num": 10,
      "teamId": 1,
      "createdAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Team",
    "createdAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z",
    "players": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Player Two",
      "num": 99,
      "teamId": 1,
      "createdAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

but I need get this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Team",
    "createdAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z",
    "players": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Player One",
        "num": 10,
        "teamId": 1,
        "createdAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Player Two",
        "num": 99,
        "teamId": 1,
        "createdAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-17T14:23:03.000Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, or if it's a problem with sequelize-typescript, or if it's a problem with sequelize.

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen if you specify: `raw: true` in the query options.

```
Team.findAll({
        include: [
            Player
        ],
        raw: true // <-- problem
    }
)
```

Results in:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Team 1",
    "players.id": 1,
    "players.name": "Player 1",
    "players.num": 1,
    "players.teamId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Team 1",
    "players.id": 2,
    "players.name": "Player 2",
    "players.num": 2,
    "players.teamId": 1
  }
]
```

Removing it:

```
Team.findAll({
        include: [
            Player
        ]
    }
)
```

Results in:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Team 1",
      "players":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Player 1",
            "num":1,
            "teamId":1
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Player 2",
            "num":2,
            "teamId":1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem. I was using `raw: true` and `nest: true` as a hook beforeFind. I didn't know that these options caused this problem.