# sequelize-typescript returns an object which has empty fields

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I followed the `sequelize-typescript` document to connect my `Model` to **`MySql`** database, and to get data from the database I used the `findAll()` method.
but I get empty fields from the response of the `findAll()` method

---

Room Model

```
@Table({
    tableName: "room",
})
export class Room extends Model<Room> {
    @PrimaryKey
    @AutoIncrement
    @Column
    id: number = -1
    
    @Column
    roomName: string = ""

    @BelongsToMany(() => User, () => PinUserRoom)
    users: User[] = []

    @HasMany(() => Message)
    messages: Message[] = []
}
```

to get data from the database I used the following code

```
Room.findAll({
        include: [Message],
    }).then((result) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
})
```

here is the log information

```
[
  {
    "roomName": "",
    "id": 2,
    "messages": []
  },
  {
    "roomName": "",
    "id": 3,
    "messages": []
  },
  {
    "roomName": "",
    "id": 4,
    "messages": []
  },
  {
    "roomName": "",
    "id": 5,
    "messages": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "passage": "",
        "roomId": -1
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "passage": "",
        "roomId": -1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

MySQL database - Room table

[image]

when I was looking for an answer, I realize when I use `raw: true` in the `findAll()` method, then everything goes right, except arrays(look at here to get more information [sequelize/sequelize-typescript - findAll with HasMany returns an object instead of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431589/sequelize-sequelize-typescript-findall-with-hasmany-returns-an-object-instead))

the JSON when using `raw: true`

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "roomName": "pv",
    "messages.id": null,
    "messages.passage": null,
    "messages.roomId": null
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "roomName": "group",
    "messages.id": null,
    "messages.passage": null,
    "messages.roomId": null
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "roomName": "bot",
    "messages.id": null,
    "messages.passage": null,
    "messages.roomId": null
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "roomName": "channel",
    "messages.id": 1,
    "messages.passage": "this is a message in channel -- 1",
    "messages.roomId": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "roomName": "channel",
    "messages.id": 2,
    "messages.passage": "this a 2nd message",
    "messages.roomId": 5
  }
]
```

why data fields are empty when not passing `raw: true`

Answer (score 0):

It happened because after the changes you didn't drop your tables.

1. Drop your tables,
2. Do the rebuild,
3. Do the migrate,

And try again to get the data